# Change Socket.IO static file serving path

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO on a Node server with a basic HTTP server (no Express or Connect or anything like that). By default, Socket.IO serves the client file to

> /socket.io/socket.io.js

I would like to be able to change that base path to something else, like

> /foo/bar/socket.io/socket.io.js

Is there any built-in way to do this, or any way without changing Socket.IO's code? I think the answer lies in the `Static` module (`require('socket.io').Static)`), but short of writing my own to replace the default, I see no way to go and change the way that behaves.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`resource` option](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) allows you to configure socket.io's root directory.  It defaults to `/socket.io`.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { resource: '/foo/bar/socket.io' });
```

Note that this setting also affects where socket.io's endpoints are served from, so **you must also change this setting in your client code**.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com', { resource: 'foo/bar/socket.io' });
```

(Note we don't use a leading slash here for some reason.)

Comment: For those just getting here, this is for versions prior to 1.0. For after 1.0, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25438603/400654) answer.

Answer (score 19):

For socket.io version **1.2.1**, this works for me.

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')({path: '/foo/bar'});
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com', {path: '/foo/bar'});
```

FYI: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences

Comment: I changed this and now my console log is showing excessive GET calls, could I have possibly done something wrong??

Answer (score 11):

If you are using socket.io **version 1.0**, the configuration is different than in previous versions.

For client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888', { path: '/some/path/socket.io' });
```

For server side

```
    var socket = require("socket.io")( { resource: '/some/path/socket.io' });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the client side script `socket.io.js` in the path `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist`. Copy it to a new folder and call it with the correct path from the client

```
<script src="/your/path/to/socket.io.js"></script>
```

For more configuration visit the [wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I have the node.js stuff in a totally different directory from the static .html page.

Comment: Not downvoting, but this is the wrong way to do it. Maintenance and upgrades (for the next guy, or future you) have just had their difficulty incremented. A friendly BTW for any others thinking this type of thing is a good idea: this concept applies to all plugins and extensions - just stick with the native support. A headache now will save many later.