# Multiple socket.io connections on the same page

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Can I connect to multiple resources on the same IP and port on the client side?

I have the following code-

```
var myIP = "192.168.1.1";
var myPort = "8080";

A = io.connect(myIP+':'+myPort,{resource: 'A/socket.io'});
B = io.connect(myIP+':'+myPort,{resource: 'B/socket.io'});

A.on('connect',console.log('A connected');
B.on('connect',console.log('B connected');

A.on('message',function(d){console.log('A: '+ d);}
B.on('message',function(d){console.log('B: '+ d);}
```

I am running [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) on `myIP:myPort`.
It is proxying connections on A and B to their respective socket-io servers.

If I run the above code on a single script, the browser ignores the second statement (It does not fires a request to resource B).

The `on(message)` callbacks for both A and B recieve the same data which actually belongs to A.

If I run the above code in two different html pages (A on one and B on other), they work fine and I get the data for both separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = io.connect(myIP+':'+myPort, {resource: 'A/socket.io', 'force new connection': true});
B = io.connect(myIP+':'+myPort, {resource: 'B/socket.io', 'force new connection': true});
```

(Yes, I removed some of the quotes)

Comment: what does the 'resource' thing do?

Comment: @RandallB: it's now called `path`. It's the path which you want to serve the socket.io static JS files from. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824612/change-socket-io-static-file-serving-path

Answer (score 1):

I would also mention Namespaces... a lot of times what you're trying to do is handle reconnect events on a per socket basis, namespaces do this for you. Their major upside is you don't need to have a connection per each one, which means they don't contribute to the 6-connections-per-domain limit of browsers.

To connect, simply do this:

`socket = io('/namespace')`