# Socket.io Multiple Connections on Client Side

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to have a multiple socket io connections on the same page (client side). I have tried this answer but unfortunately it did not solved the problem, [Link to SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901688/multiple-socket-io-connections-on-the-same-page)

Case:

- I have a chat(bot) application running on localhost:3000
- I have a CMS for the said chat(bot) application running on localhost:8000

My code currently:

1.Declare Script on index.html, (on localhost:3000)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

2. Socket.io logic on main.js (on localhost:3000)

```
var socket          = io('http://localhost:3000', {resource: '/socket.io', forceNew : true});
var cms_socket      = io('http://localhost:8000', {resource: '/socket.io', forceNew : true});

socket.on('connect', console.log("SOCKET IO chat connected")) //WORKED
cms_socket.on('connect', console.log("SOCKET IO cms_connected")); //WORKED

socket.on('bot-reply', (data) => alert(data)) //WORKED
cms_socket.on('test_cms_socket', (data) => alert(data)) //NOT-WORKED
```

What confuses me is that the **console log from both socket worked**, telling both socket connects, though the `cms_socket.on('test_cms_socket', ..)` did not work.

Here is the logic from the CMS localhost:8000

```
function broadcast(req,res){
   res.io.emit('test_cms_socket', "This is from CMS");
   return res.redirect('/');
}
```

I have passed my socket.io to the middleware, used a tutorial from [here](https://github.com/onedesign/express-socketio-tutorial)

I do not really know if this helps or not, but I get this error from console. Any help would be very much appreciated

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at r.emit (index.js:133)
    at r.emit (socket.js:136)
    at r.onconnect (socket.js:327)
    at r.onpacket (socket.js:224)
    at r.<anonymous> (index.js:21)
    at r.emit (index.js:133)
    at r.ondecoded (manager.js:345)
    at s.<anonymous> (index.js:21)
    at s.r.emit (index.js:133)
    at s.add (index.js:241)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901688/multiple-socket-io-connections-on-the-same-page

Comment: @daviscodesbugs yeah, i have tried the solution but it did not work for me. *I have also linked it in my first paragraph