# single connection is used when connecting to different namespaces

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Initial primary connection is created as follows on the login page:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

Later when the user logs in I'm creating socket for new namespace as follows:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/register',{ forceNew: false });
```

But the new socket is replacing the primary socket connection.
Isnt it supposed to use the old primary connection and keep the socketid same?
Is there any way to keep the newly created namespace connection same as primary connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one connection on the same page, you need to create new variables for it. Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901688/multiple-socket-io-connections-on-the-same-page)

Comment: No no. Both are different pages. I wanted to see if the socketid generated on second page could be kept similar to the socketid of firstpage.

Comment: have tried to do it with a different variable name ? @BlackHeart

Comment: Yes I did. When the /register page loads the socketid created on first page is overridden by the socketid created  on /register page

Comment: have you tried to do like this `var socketOne = io('http://localhost:3000');` and `var socketTwo = io('http://localhost:3000/register',{ forceNew: false });`

Comment: when you are going to the new page?

Comment: i think you should give them a value of resource, as the default resource value might be overriding

Comment: Yes  I used two different variables and they are on two different pages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the solution @BlackHeart